# Escape HTML with java but keep some characters

Tags: java, html, escaping

Basically what I want to do is html escape a string but not escape characters like `åäö` etc.

I basically want to escape these characters.

```
&, <, >, ", ', `, , !, @, $, %, (, ), =, +, {, }, [, and ]
```

Sure I'm not completely safe in some context but in I should be fine. Right now I've been using `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(String))` but it's escaping `åäö`.

So do I have to create my own function with replace or is there a finished function out there?

Comment: Why would you want to escape `!`, `@` and so on? The only characters that *need* escaping should be `&` `<` `>` and quotes

Comment: To be honest, it would be very easy to construct your own regex for this, probably easier than finding a standard function the caters to your specific needs

Comment: Pekka: http://wonko.com/post/html-escaping

Comment: Too bad, oh well time to work then ;)

Comment: How about using JSOUP and the Cleaner class [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer) combined with a whitelist ?

Comment: @Vejto: the article is wrong, IMO. You need to escape more than `&`, `>`, `<`, `"` and `'` if your application generates invalid HTML code, and doesn't properly encode link parameters. But adding more escaping is not a solution for sloppiness and incorrect HTML. Generate valid HTML, escaping only the 5 characters that need to be escaped, and everything will be fine.

Comment: Also, why do you call escapeJavaScript to escape HTML? Doing that will, for example, replace all your newline chars with `\n`, your tags to `\t`, etc. You don't want user-posted content to look like literal JavaScript strings, do you?

Comment: This is a bit old code and that is why I'm looking to replace it. Since I'm not the only one building this application I wanted to make sure everything was safe. But I guess you are right, I rather should make everyone write proper code!